# Logging whole flow of application for easy reading

Tags: java, spring, logging

In my web application(Spring based), i have simple layered architecture as Service->Manager->Dao->database. For logging purpose i want to log request coming to Service and then exit from Service at one go so that it is easy to debug issues. Otherwise logs contain various output from different threads intermingle with each other which is not easy to read. Is it possible with existing logging framework like log4j.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with any logging framework. You can use AOP to create a "logging" aspect around your service methods. Here is some [example](http://thoughtforge.net/2010/02/16/creating-a-logging-aspect-with-spring-aop-and-aspectj/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) to implement such logs. Here's an example:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("call(* com.yourcompany.*.*(..))")
    public void serviceMethod() {
    }

    @Before("serviceMethod()")
    public void logMethodCalls(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
            LOG.debug("Calling method {} with args {}",
                joinPoint.getSignature(), joinPoint.getArgs());
    }

}
```

Just wire it as a Spring Bean:

```
<bean class="com.somepackage.LoggingAspect" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

and calls to public methods of Spring beans in the matched packages should be logged.

Comment: Let me specify what i need with example.  I have 3 layers , Userservice(authenticate method),UserManager(authenticateUser),UserDaoImpl(authenticate method). What i need in log is like following "In UserService.authenticate , parameters are.... , some other logging statements in autheticate, In UserManager.authenticate ....In UserDaoImpl.authenticate method........," then log of other request follows. In your way i can only  log one method but this method can also log something. I need all of log which generates in single request sequencially so that it is easy to debug.

Comment: do you say that you want to accumulate all logging messages during single service request from all layers and then log them all at once when service method exits?

Comment: yes but since i currently don't know how to do it, i just implemented simple solution of logging, log all messages as it occurs in application